# Insert value in empty string JS

Tags: javascript, string

Why doesn't this work in JS ? I need to keep on adding a value to empty in for loop

```
let lang = "";
lang[0] = "J";
lang[1] = "S";
console.log(lang);//''
```

Why it sets to empty string ?

```
I was expecting 
let lang = "";
lang[0] = "J";
lang[1] = "S";
console.log(lang);//JS
```

Comment: JavaScript strings are immutable.

Comment: You cannot write to strings. They are read-only. You can however assign a new string to your variable: `lang = lang + "J"`